# Natural sort to multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a api that returns requested images paths to front end. But in Linux server its needs natural sorting. I want to natural sort values in the `yol` key.

```
$klein->respond('GET', '/getPaths/[:name]', function($request,$response) {

$path00 = "../manga/" . $request->name;

function getAll($path00)
{
$dirs = [];
foreach (new DirectoryIterator($path00) as $item) {
    if (!$item->isDir() || $item->isDot()) {
        continue;
    }
    $gedo = [];
    $path01  = $path00 . "/" . $item;
    $path02 = substr($path01, 3);
    $yol = new DirectoryIterator($path01);
    foreach ($yol as $esya) {
        if (!$esya->isDot() && $esya->getFilename() !== ".DS_Store") {
            $gedo[] = $path02 . "/" .  $esya->getFilename();

        }
    }

    $dirs[] = array('klasor' => $item->getFilename(), 'yol' => $gedo);
}

return $dirs; // Output its in the image.
};

$data = getAll($path00);
$response->json($data);
});
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: There's no _question_, what are you asking?

Comment: The guy needs to natural sort his array for a specific series of indices and asks us to do that for him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at PHP [sort functions](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php). [natsort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php) should work for your case.

Simply change the following line to this:

```
    natsort($gedo);
    $dirs[] = array('klasor' => $item->getFilename(), 'yol' => $gedo);
```

Also a simple code example:

```
    $input = [
        'abc' => [
            'item1',
            'item4',
            'item2'
        ]
    ];

    $output = natsort($input['abc']); // $output will be true
    // but $input is now sorted and looking like:
    // 'abc' => [
    //     'item1',
    //     'item2',
    //     'item4'
    // ]
```

Comment: No thats return boelan for values.

Comment: @Nasuh Yes, that is correct. According to the documentation it returns true or false depending on whether the sort was successful or not. Check my updated above.